# Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, upload, permissions, xampp

I created php files for my plugin and added them to myplugin folder. Then I zipped myplugin folder as myplugin.zip. In Admin Panel of Wordpress I wanted to install my plugin to wordpress. I choosed this zip file and clicked to Install "Now button". Then Wordpress gave an error:

> Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/2013/05. Is its parent directory writable by the server?

What is the problem and how can I solve it? My OS is `Linux` and I use `XAMPP` server in my machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your terminal, navigate to the wp-content folder and then run:

```
chmod -R 0744 plugins
```

That will set the folder and its subfolders to read/write/execute for you and read for everyone else.

**Edit**  As suggested in the comments, check this out: codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions

**Alternatively** you can just unzip them yourself and save them into this folder:

```
/wp-content/plugins/name-of-theplugin
```

Then you can just activate the plugin from the admin page.

Comment: If you'd like more info on WordPress permissions, go here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions

Comment: @vlasits , it is not working with `0744`, tried `0777`, works fine.

Comment: @vlasits, and we must change the folder with name `plugins`, not `uploads`. And your answer is great! Thanks!

Comment: @vlasits, edit your answer, please, edit 744 to 777 and uploads to plugins

Comment: @ZiyaddinSadigov It might be ok and/or necessary for you to change to 777 on your local machine, but since it is a *bad* idea on a public-facing server, I'll leave my answer with the 744 and leave the comments here to point people in a similar situation as you to the solution you found.

Comment: 0777 worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely familiar with XAMPP but it should be run as a user. Most likely your own windows account. You may try this:

Select the folder wp-content and right click -> properties. then go to Security Tab. There check to see if the User (i.e. you) has write+ modify permission.

Check what is XAMPP server running as, the folder above must have the permissions for the same user.
Double check the "general" tab on the wp-content folder and check the "Attributes" section. Make sure "Read Only is unchecked. If you are changing it, windows will prompt for whether to apply to subfolder. Say "yes".

. Or run XAMPP at Administrator and skip the above step .(assuming it is not production / public internet facing server).

Comment: my OS is Linux. Can you explain for Linux?

Comment: Linux is actually easier. I thought you're on Windows. Xampp is basically a set of packages specific to your distro. In fedora/redhat/centos RPM style distros the directory should be owned by user "apache" on debian/ubuntu it is "www-data" A 
#chown -R apache will do the trick for you. No need to reboot or restart process.

However the xampp site says they run the apache as user "nobody". So in your case it is most likely:

#chown -R nobody <your web root>

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem yesterday, I solved it by uninstalling the Wordpress module and installing it again as root from the terminal.

I thought if I run the installation wizard as I was logged as root was enough, but it wasn't.

These are the steps for MacOS:

1. Uninstall wordpress module. Be sure the folder is empty.
2. Mount the wordpress disk image
3. cd /volumes/nameOfWordpressModule image
4. sudo bitnami wordpress module.app/Contents/MacOS/installerbuilder.sh

I recommend you to list the items so you can write exactly the name of the image and app.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for MacOS version for MacOS users, Ana Gomez!

Comment: Sorry, this is for Linux: chmod 755 bitnami-wordpress-version-Linux.run after unistalling wordpress. Then double click on the file to open it.

Answer (score 1):

navigate to your main project folder and run the following:

```
chmod -R 0777 wp-content
```

Answer (score 1):

in case of MAC run 
`sudo chmod -R 777 /Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/`